# PHP memory exhausted although memory limit not reached

Tags: php

I am currently debugging a php-script.
I set the memory_limit to 64M and it confirms this:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","64M");
echo "starting script with ".ini_get("memory_limit")."Bytes of ram\n"; \\64
```

But nevertheless the script breaks using just 20M giving the standard memory exhausted error.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 20971520 byte exhausted
```

Is there a possibility I probably did not think of ?
Maybe Apache is setting something for PHP ?

Comment: Please quote the exact error along with the numbers it shows

Comment: How do you measure the memory usage? I ask because the memory_get_usage() and memory_get_peak_usage() functions only returns the real memory usage if you pass it a boolean `True`.

Comment: From the docs: "Prior to PHP 5.2.1, in order to use this directive it had to be enabled at compile time by using --enable-memory-limit in the configure line."

Comment: @wuschelhase , i also faced such problem when i did some stuff with `images` on a php page, r u also doing same??

Comment: You are sure you edited the correct php.ini? There are two different for CLI and Web execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe the `safe_mode` is enabled on your server - if so, a lot of settings can't be changed using `ini_set()`. please take a look at your php.ini and check that.

**EDIT:** what happens if you change the value for memory_limit in the php.ini directly and restart/reload your apache (or whatever)? does it work in that case?

**EDIT2** to wuschelhases comment:

- have you restarted the apache after changing the php.ini? are you really sure you changed the correct php.ini (there may be not only one)?
- what OS are your running (is this a linux-server, windows-server or a simple xampp-installation on your windows-home-pc)?
- what does [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.phpinfo.php) say about the memory-limit?

Comment: @wuschelhase Look into `phpinfo()` to see the exact path of the php.ini that is being used. Chances are you are not editing the correct one.

Comment: it was safe_mode, found it in phpinfo()

Answer (score 4):

Better try this for unlimited memory:

```
ini_set("memory_limit",-1)
```